# What will happen if the far end doesn’t support any of the mentioned codecs in invite? And how to resolve it?

Tags: sip, voip

What happens when far end doesn’t support any of the mentioned codecs in the invite? And how to resolve it?

Comment: Whatever that "far end" is: is this in any way related to programming?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question can be found in [RFC3261](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) which specifies the SIP protocol. I recommend reading it before you start with SIP.

The user agent server (UAS, the 'far'end') will return a final failure response. Most likely 606 Not Acceptable since it doesn't support any of the codecs offered.

The response may contain an SDP body containing the media capabilities the UAS does support. If this body contains media codecs the user agent client (UAC) also supports the UAC can decide to send a new INVITE request containing this set of media codecs.

Comment: Isn't there any device or any system to convert the codec to another one supported by the far end?